# Ruby on Rails with CanCanCan Gem - Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Ability (ruby 2.2.3 - rails 4.2.6)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cancancan

I started to receive the following error in production.

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Ability
  from active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
  from active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  from active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
  from active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  from active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
  from active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
  from app/controllers/frontend/application_controller.rb:126:in `current_ability'
  from cancan/controller_additions.rb:352:in `authorize!'
  from app/controllers/documentable_count_controller.rb:5:in `index'
  from action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  from abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  from abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  from abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  from active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  from active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  from active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  from action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  from action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  from active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  from abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  from action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  from action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  from action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  from action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  from action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  from action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  from action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  from action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  from action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  from action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  from rack/attack.rb:172:in `call'
  from warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  from warden/manager.rb:35:in `catch'
  from warden/manager.rb:35:in `call'
  from rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  from rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  from rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  from rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  from rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  from active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  from active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  from active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  from rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  from rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  from active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  from rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  from ahoy/engine.rb:22:in `call_with_quiet_ahoy'
  from request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  from rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  from rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  from active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  from action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  from rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  from rack/cors.rb:97:in `call'
  from raven/integrations/rack.rb:50:in `call'
  from rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  from rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  from rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  from puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
  from puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
  from puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
  from puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
  from puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `call'
  from puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I tried to check if somebody has the problem and some of the posts said to set the "config.eager_load" to true. However, it is already set this way in production.

The problem starts when the code try check if the user is authorized to read a building in the line "authorize! :read, @building".

```rb
class DocumentableCountController < ::Frontend::ApplicationController
  before_action :redirect_if_no_building

  def index
    authorize! :read, @building

    ...
  end

  ...
```

It calls the following method under the hood where the error occurs which is in the "@current_ability ||= Ability.new(stakeholder)" line.

```rb
module Frontend
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController
    ...
    def current_ability
      stakeholder = current_admin || current_user

      @current_ability ||= Ability.new(stakeholder)
    end
  end
end
```

It gives the error:

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Ability
```

It is expected to not have this error.

## Extra info

The following code is the "::ApplicationController" class inherited by the Module Frontend above.

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include HasFrontendPartner
  include RescuesNotFound

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to "/403", notice: exception.message }
      format.json { render json: { error: exception.message }, status: 403 }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the idea behind `ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder, thanks for the reply. I added its content in the description.

Comment: Please add the full backtrace errors, otherwise we're shooting in the dark

Comment: @lacostenycoder, sorry about that. I just added the entire error description.

Comment: Could you please sahre the code of your `Ability` class?